# Do I need to convert sklearn predict_proba() return value from logit to probability like I do with glm?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, prediction

Do I need to convert `sklearn predict_proba()`return value from logit to probability like I do with glm? This question was prompted by an extremely narrow distribution of probabilities around the .5 threshold on a simple logistic regression output.

The question was posed: are these true probabilities because the dispersion appears too narrow.  I have subsequently applied `CalibratedClassifierCV` which has increased the 'spread' of the probability outcomes, and this may help solve the problem, but the issue is whether the `predict_proba` needs to be modified like logit:

```
def log_convert(prob):
            prob = math.exp(prob)/(1+math.exp(prob))
            return prob
          
calc_prob = [log_convert(x) for x in probability]
```

The docs suggest there's some `softmax()` applied, and the results of applying conversion suggest that such conversion isn't necessary, but I wanted to ask.